# Automatically grab text from email, and push to csv?

Tags: python, scripting

Suppose I get a daily email with the following consistent format:

```
Daily Report
X, Y, Z
1, 2, 3
3, 4, 5
., ., .
```

With X/Y/Z being the "titles" of columns, and each number respectively corresponding to it.

Is there a way to pull this column format from my inbox and throw it into a csv file every day? The email client is Outlook.

Comment: `Is there a way...?`  Yes, pretty much anything can be done with computers if you set your mind to it.  However, I doubt you will get much help here unless you show an honest effort to solve this problem yourself.  SO isn't a "code for me for free please" site.  People here like to see what you've tried yourself.  Then, they will be glad to help you with any specific problems you are having.

Comment: I have had some success automatically parsing email using Python's `imapclient` library.

Comment: @iCodez: "pretty much anything", +1 for that!

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally like to just use link as an answer to the question but for your question, I think it will be the best solution:

> - Firstly, you need to be able to read Outlook Email with Python. The following link has the nice and clean example of this which you can
>     modify for your use. [Reading Outlook Email With Python](http://softwaretestautomationnotes.blogspot.com/2011/11/reading-outlook-email-with-python.html)
> - Second, for the body of your email, you have to import `csv` module
>     from python. Here is the link from the documentation.[csv — CSV File Reading and Writing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)